# What is the equivalent C/C++ loselose algorithm in python

Tags: python, c++, c, algorithm, hash

For a particular reason I am trying to find (not exhaustively) the worst hash algorithm. I found [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed) analyzing some, and I targeted the Loselose algorithm. [This page](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html) states the algorithm in C (I think) as:

```
unsigned long hash(unsigned char *str)
{
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
        hash += c;

    return hash;
}
```

I'm not a programmer, and C (or C++ ?) of this block is killing me. Could you please give me a help and provide the equivalent in python?

PS.: For those asking "why the worst hash?",I intend to create set2, an  "equivalent" to an original set1, but reduced in elements due to high algorithm hash collisions. I don't need to go back to the original set1. I just need to know if a hash is present in set2.

Comment: `while (c = *str++)` is equivalent to `while ((c = *str++) != 0)`.

Comment: This is no translation service.

Comment: FWIW, I think the closest Python equivalent would be `def hash(s): return sum(bytearray(s))`.

Comment: Surely the worst hash algorithm is just `return 0;` (or any other constant)?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - any constant except 42, of course.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - I get your point... but the idea is to have a hash set2 that still represents the characteristics of set1. Therefore set2 contains a representation of elements of set1 but not otherwise.  Instead of searching set1, I search in set2 which is smaller. This is getting away from the topic title, but thanks anyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ code that you have provided simply iterates over each character of the given string and adds its ASCII value to the variable `hash` and returns the `hash`.

We can achieve the same in Python 2.7 by doing this:

```
def custom_hash(s):
  hsh = 0
  for c in s: hsh += ord(c)
  return hsh
```

Or you can always try to be Pythonic and do the same in one line :)

```
hsh = reduce(lambda x, y: ord(x) + ord(y), list(s))
```